# FLEX 3 : library for pie charts and vertical gauge

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, charts, flex3, gauge

Which is the best library to build pie charts and vertical gauge with Flex 3 ?
I like Fusioncharts. Other alternatives ?

What about Anychart ?

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through FusionCharts as well as Anycharts, and after using the products specially the pie charts and vertical gauge(specified by you), I would suggest you to go with [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/pie-doughnut-charts/). One of the basic comparison between both the charts is the charts of Fusioncharts can be rotated clockwise as well as anticlockwise, which looks preety good from my end. I hope my suggestions will help you.

Thank You